# Scrapy pipelines order is jumbled when a particular pipeline is included

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I have 6 pipelines, defined like this in settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 100,
    #'SiteCrawler.pipelines.ScreenshotPipeline': 200,
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.NodesPipeline': 300,
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.EdgesPipeline': 400,
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.ParentsPipeline': 500,
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.TextAnalysisPipeline': 600,
}
```

When the Screenshot pipeline is left out like this, the pipelines operate in the correct order. I know this, because I log when each pipeline is used. The method to create the order is [the one suggested in the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component). However, when I include the Screenshot pipeline, the order becomes jumbled. 1,3,4,5,6 becomes 6,4,2,5,3,1. I need them to be in the correct order.

Here is the code for the Screenshots pipeline, in case anything in there can explain it:

```
class ScreenshotPipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.date = spider.unix_date
        self.domain = spider.scrape_domain
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path)
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        log.msg("screenshot")
        try:
            self.driver.get(item['url_obj'].full)
        except:
            self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path)
            self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
            self.driver.get(item['url_obj'].full)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=2)
        self.driver.save_screenshot(r"{0}\initiator\static\scrapes\{1}\{2}\{3}.png".format(getcwd(), self.domain, self.date, item['url_obj'].name))
        return item

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        pass
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with pipelines.  They are not ordered according to the indices given in the ITEM_PIPELINES dictionary.  I renamed the pipelines and, oddly, the order of execution changed.  But, it still wasn't the correct order.

Finally, I changed ITEM_PIPELINES from a dictionary to a list (in the desired order of execution), and that worked.  According to the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html):

```
Lists are supported in ITEM_PIPELINES for backwards compatibility, but they are deprecated.
```

So, you could try setting your pipelines as follows (as long as lists continue to be supported):

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline',
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.ScreenshotPipeline',
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.NodesPipeline',
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.EdgesPipeline',
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.ParentsPipeline',
    'SiteCrawler.pipelines.TextAnalysisPipeline',
]
```

Comment: Problem still sometimes shows up but unfortunately this doesn't work in Python 3 - Scrapy 1.8.